# socket not released after service restart

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, service, restart

There is:
A: program that holds open socket
B: watch dog script running as service :

```
while true
do
        if [ -z "`pidofproc $1`" ]; then
                $1;
            chrt -f -p 40 `pidofproc $1`
                sleep 8
        fi;
        sleep 2
done
```

when service started - watch dog started
when service stopped - watch dog and program are killed (killall).

now program wants to upgrade itself, so it calls `system( "upgrade.sh" );`

upgrade.sh:

```
/sbin/service watchdog stop

.... install upgrade  .....

exec /sbin/service watchdog start &
```

upgrade performed successfully, but when program starts - can't open socket (already in use) - on this error - program quits (to be restarted by watch dog).

lsof -i shows three programs on the port:

```
watchdog

program

sleep
```

program and sleep pids always change (i.e. quit/restart behavior)

watchdog pid persistant.

i tried to replace `system(...)`, with

`if(!fork()) exec(...)` , but same problem remains.

Comment: It would be far more useful if you showed the code that tries to open the socket instead of some totally unrelated scripts... As a wild guess I would say you should read about SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: there is no SO_REUSEADDR in socket creation. i want to keep it this way. why socket not released?

Comment: There is acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true), ec);
 acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true), ec); 
 acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::linger(true, 200), ec);

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how fast the restart happens after the shut down, the socket will be lingering around. Linux, by default, keeps sockets marked as in use for some time after they've been released (either by `close()` or when the process dies) to make sure that incoming connection attempts or data which is late due to network latencies won't end up at the wrong application.

This has to be fixed inside the application. It is required to set the `SO_REUSEADDR` sockopt. As per the manpage of socket(7):

> Indicates that the rules used in validating  addresses  supplied
>   in  a  bind(2)  call should allow reuse of local addresses.  For
>   AF_INET sockets this means that a socket may bind,  except  when
>   there  is an active listening socket bound to the address.  When
>   the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a specific port
>   then  it  is  not  possible  to  bind to this port for any local
>   address.  Argument is an integer boolean flag.

This has to be set using `setsockopt` after the socket was created.

Comment: so if i don't want to use SO_REUSEADDR, should i add sleep 60 in upgrade script